# The reference of ‘that’ in this context?

Tags: reference

To what does the highlighted ‘that’ refer? To ‘bond’ or to ‘climate policy’?

> Earlier, however, the Paris Agreement, adopted to
> general enthusiasm in December 2015, had foreshadowed the emergence of
> a new kind of diplomacy aimed at bringing the concert of nations into
> the era of climate change awareness. Despite the weaknesses that
> underlay this agreement, it was this attempt to forge a bond between
> diplomatic cooperation and climate policy **that** was attacked by the
> new masters of chaos: there was no question of founding a world order
> on any limitation of the economy.

Comment: that always refers to the preceding term.

Comment: It refers to "attempt to forge a bond between diplomatic cooperation and climate policy".

Comment: The structure of the cited text is no different to *It was Janet **that*** (or ***who***) *attacked John* and *It was here **that** I met your mother*.

Answer (score 3):

The reference in this context is not the *bond* or *climate policy* in this text, rather it refers to the *attempt to forge a bond between diplomatic cooperation and climate policy* as a whole.

Comment: I agree, except that the determiner "this" (your "the") is not part of the antecedent. Integrated (defining) relative clauses modify nominals, not noun phrases.

Comment: @BillJ , you were right, that was an accident. Thanks!